# How can I improve the performance of Linux-based Docker Desktop containers running R scripts on Windows 10?

Tags: r, linux, powershell, docker, containers

I'd like to be able to get the same performance with docker as I get in RStudio. I have Docker Desktop installed on Windows 10 and am using Linux containers. The goal is to containerize R scripts for general use. An R script **dtbenchmark.R** (adapted from the data.table benchmark script by [Matt Dowle](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping)), that encapsulates the problem that I'm having, is

```
library(data.table)
K <- 100L
rows <- c(1e7L, 1:7*1e8L)
for (i in 1:length(rows)) {
  tme <- proc.time()
  N <- rows[i]
  set.seed(1)
  DT <- data.table(
    id1 = sample(sprintf("id%03d",1:K), N, TRUE),       # large groups (char)
    id2 = sample(sprintf("id%03d",1:K), N, TRUE),       # large groups (char)
    id3 = sample(sprintf("id%010d",1:(N/K)), N, TRUE),  # small groups (char)
    id4 = sample(K, N, TRUE),                           # large groups (int)
    id5 = sample(K, N, TRUE),                           # large groups (int)
    id6 = sample(N/K, N, TRUE),                         # small groups (int)
    v1 =  sample(5, N, TRUE),                           # int in range [1,5]
    v2 =  sample(5, N, TRUE),                           # int in range [1,5]
    v3 =  sample(round(runif(100,max=100),4), N, TRUE)) # numeric e.g. 23.5749
  GB <- round(sum(gc()[,2])/1024, 3)
  rt <- round(proc.time() - tme, 2)
  print(paste0('i = ', i, ' N = ', N, ' K = ', K, ' GB = ', GB, ' seconds = ', rt[3]), quote = FALSE)
  rm(N, DT, GB, rt)
}
```

The **Dockerfile** is

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.4.3
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/data.table/data.table_1.12.0.tar.gz', repo = NULL, type = 'source')" 
COPY . /root
WORKDIR /root
CMD ["Rscript", "dtbenchmark.R"]
```

In RStudio, the script **dtbenchmark.R** is able to get through five loops, before exiting with an error message, as in

```
[1] i = 1 N = 10000000 K = 100 GB = 0.532 seconds = 2.64
[1] i = 2 N = 100000000 K = 100 GB = 4.954 seconds = 44.58
[1] i = 3 N = 200000000 K = 100 GB = 9.868 seconds = 170.53
[1] i = 4 N = 300000000 K = 100 GB = 14.778 seconds = 426.42
[1] i = 5 N = 400000000 K = 100 GB = 19.688 seconds = 1013.77
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.7 Gb
```

With the **Dockerfile** and **dtbenchmark.R** in the same folder, in Windows PowerShell the docker command in that folder to build the image is

```
docker build -t dtbenchmark .
```

Then the docker command in Windows PowerShell to run the container is

```
docker run --rm dtbenchmark:latest
```

In PowerShell, the container only gets through three loops, before exiting with no message, as in

```
[1] i = 1 N = 10000000 K = 100 GB = 0.515 seconds = 2.08
[1] i = 2 N = 100000000 K = 100 GB = 4.937 seconds = 41.3
[1] i = 3 N = 200000000 K = 100 GB = 9.851 seconds = 91.81
```

My laptop has Windows 10 Enterprise, 48 GB of RAM and a 64-bit OS. I'm not able to run as administrator.

Comment: That's a very nice first question. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm completely unfamiliar with this process but from a Powershell standpoint, when I need a process to complete quickly I always run a foreach loop and process in parallel.  By default Powershell will process 5 loops in parallel at a time but you could experiment with upping that number.

Possibly:

```
    foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 5 ($container in $containers){ 

          #do something

   }
```